# 3 of 4 plots are empty while using matplotlib in Pycharm and using plt.show()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, pycharm

I'm trying to learn to use Python 3.7.3 in PyCharm for data science. I went to this website to understand the workflow in a data science project.

https://www.districtdatalabs.com/how-to-start-your-first-data-science-project

I've installed matplotlib and pandas and got them working. I'm using matplotlib to do data visualization. I'm trying to plot the Age, Sibling list, Parchment, and Fare of survivors into four separate plots, but only the "Age" plot is showing data.  The Sibling list, parchment, and Fare plots are empty of data. I've tried plt.show(), plt.show(block=True), plt.show(block=False), and they do not result in displaying all 4 plots of data. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Thompsat\Documents\Saf\Thom\dscience\train.csv')
print(df)
print(df.head())
print(df.describe())

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20,10)

# make subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

# specifying features of interest. create lists and variables with the features in the plots.
num_features = ['Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare']
xaxes = num_features
yaxes = ['Counts', 'Counts', 'Counts', 'Counts']

# draw histograms
axes = axes.ravel()
for idx, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.hist(df[num_features[idx]].dropna(), bins=40)
    ax.set_xlabel(xaxes[idx], fontsize=20)
    ax.set_ylabel(yaxes[idx], fontsize=20)
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=15)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to put `plt.show()` outside the loop.

Comment: That worked! I don't know why it worked, but thanks!!!

Comment: You created one figure with 4 subplots. So you need to fill them all 4 to see them all. If you want to see them one by one, you create a figure with only 1 subplot, and use show() inside the loop. Note that plt.show() normally will block (pause) the programming, but also clear the plot when you close the plot window.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm still unclear on how to use matplotlib. I've been looking at the matplotlib documentation.